# Как с помощью кнопки открыть DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, button, android-navigation-drawer

Доброго времени суток. Как сделать так, чтобы выдвижное меню открывалось по нажатию на определённую кнопку? Я знаю, что можно через `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, но это не то. `ActionBar` и `Toolbar` не использую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
```

Ссылка на [доку](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(int))